# What does this serpentine section do in this case break on a Samsung dishwasher?

Tags: dishwasher

[image]

I can not find any info about it, and it is hard to diagnose problems with this part without fully understanding how it is supposed to work.

Here is a stock photo showing this same (except brand new) case break from the other side with the red arrow pointing to where the maze is...

[image]

Comment: Soap or rinse agent dispenser.

Comment: @crip659 I do not think so. On this unit, the detergent is dispensed from a pop-open compartment inside the washer bay.  This little maze connects to the drain line, so I think might be some kind of a vent?

Comment: I vote anti-siphon

Comment: Location? Size? Seeing it in context would help.

Comment: @keshlam I've added a photo of the full case break with an arrow showing where the maze is.

Comment: I think you probably know that one part of that whole assembly is a flow sensor for incoming fresh water, and another part is an antisiphon for the drain.   I think you are asking about the remaining parts.   It's a mystery indeed, but it seems to be some kind of pressure-related feedback loop between the inflow and drain.  Two wild guesses: 1) A vent for the anti-siphon, 2) to allow drain water to flow back into the machine if the drain is blocked, and hence distinguish between a blocked drain and a faulty drain pump.   Neither of these explain why it's serpentine.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because "how does this part of my appliance work" doesn't fit within the scope of home improvement. There's no indication that there's even a problem here, just idle curiosity - not that there's anything wrong with idle curiosity...

Comment: @Freeman The machine is continuously draining. Flow sensor, leak sensor, overfill sensor all check good. It is hard to diagnose and fix an issue when there is a part of the system that you do not understand how it works or what it does! Would you close a question "how does the amount of water in a cement mixture effect strength?" because there is no indication that a building is actually falling down? :)

Comment: What sort of things do the wires connect to?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because the question should address the actual problem rather than be about asking what a specific part does.

Comment: @steve One set comes from the flow sensor (round), the other set comes from the overflow sensor (rectangle).

Comment: @gnicko Why? This question falls into both "Identifying the source or cause of a problem within your home" and "Installation, maintenance, and repair of major appliances" and does not seem to even touch on any of the diy SE considered-off-topic bullets.  I do not seem any mention of anything like "question should address the actual problem rather than be about asking what a specific part does" anywhere in the guidelines.

Comment: @bigjosh How is this question (as written) useful to anyone else?

Comment: @gnicko anyone who is diagnosing a problem with their dishwasher and gets to the point where they have narrowed the issue down to the case break but can not proceed any farther because they do not know what this section does so do not know how to test if it is working correctly or not correctly (me right now!). And apparently this is not common knowledge and it is not in the service manual which suggests just replacing the whole assembly. How far could you get figuring out why your car does not start if you did not know what a spark plug was? Would you just replace the whole ignition system?

Comment: @bigjosh Before or after checking the air in the tires?

Answer (score 2):

**It's the air path for the drain anti-siphon.**

Here's an annotated photo showcasing the extent of my graphics skills (or more precisely, the lack thereof):

[image: annotated photo of the part]

The maze is on the path which the air from the inside of the dishwasher takes to get into the downcoming segment of the drain line to break any siphon action, so basically the same as a vent line in domestic drain plumbing.

I can only wildly speculate as to why it is serpentine, perhaps to stop some random backsplash from the drain line from getting all the way back into the interior of the dishwasher, or to act as a mini-trap to stop smells from the drain line from propagating back.

Either way, judging from your photo which seems to have the entire drain line full of water, I suspect the air path is just clogged up with gunk and not doing its job. You'll probably have to take the part out and use air or water to clear the blockage.